# Music video comic/cartoon like, detective and woman and mob

Tags: identify-this-song

I'm looking for song, probably years 80's/90's. What i remember is music video that was cartoon-like, but technique was comic-like. Pictures was rather static - movement seemed as painted for comic. Some action was by moving objects apart of the main picture.
Dialogues as far as i remember comic-like, subtitles in balloons boxes.

Persons - woman ala usa 60's, in motel bar. Man - ala 60's detective - coat, hat. Two bodyguards/mob thugs, big guys in suits, hats.

At some point thugs takes woman in to car. Probably there was chase on the road, but i can't really remember :)

Drawing style of pictures was probably like this one (comics no 11, 19): [Detective Comics Values: Issues #11 to #20](http://www.sellmycomicbooks.com/detective-comics-values-11-20.html) so, it could be that i was wrong and the style of drawing, and reality is shown as in 30s in USA.

Regards,
Marcin

Comment: @Bebs Hello, i guess it was pop or light rock. Unfortunately mostly i remember, that i liked it... I was also unable to find it myself trying many queries regarding all i remember.

Comment: Can you check if it is *Pearl Jam - Do the Evolution* or *U2 - Hold Me, Thrill Me, Kiss Me, Kill Me* ? Thank you =)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Based on your edit.

I believe it is

**The Alan Parsons Project - Don't Answer Me
Video:**
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JLvFbBR4XOg

Comment: I saw title and knew Yoy are right. Thank You. Its funny that it is so hard to find by Search.

Answer (score 1):

Is it possible this song?

A-Ha - Take on me.

[**Here**](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=djV11Xbc914) the You Tube Video

Published year: 1985

Included in: **Hunting High and Low** album

[**Here**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Take_On_Me) Wikipedia page about this song

Comment: It is not the one i'm looking for.  But it's really nice video and song :)

Comment: sorry dear, but I'm happy for video and song

Answer (score 0):

Can it be > Radiohead, 'Paranoid Android' I can not think of anything that comes closer. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sPLEbAVjiLA

Comment: altough very interesting is not the one i thought about :)

Answer (score 0):

It's a long shot, for several reasons, but Weird Al Yankovic's Miley Cyrus parody ["Party in the CIA"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=C-CG5w4YwOI) features a 60's style animated video with chase sequences.  The main character is a spy, not a detective, but many of the tropes are similar.

Comment: it was far older and different in styling